# Polymer routing when refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am currently working on a polymer application and my previous application was also built with polymer. In the previous app I did the routing and it worked perfectly.

I went back to the old code and tried to implement it in the new app with total failure.

I cannot for the life of me see what I have done differently.

```
   <link rel="import" href="app-theme.html">
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="routing-element-two.html">

<dom-module id="routing-element-one">
<template id="test-element-template">
    <style include="iron-flex">

    </style>
    <app-location route="{{route}}"></app-location>

    <app-route
        route="{{route}}"
        pattern="/polymerui/:page"
        data="{{routeData}}">
    </app-route>
        test one
    <paper-tabs selected='{{routeData.page}}' attr-for-selected='key'>
      <paper-tab key='main'>main</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab key='document'>document</paper-tab>
      <paper-tab key='baz'>Baz!</paper-tab>
    </paper-tabs>

    <neon-animated-pages selected='{{routeData.page}}'
                     attr-for-selected='key'
                     entry-animation='slide-from-left-animation'
                     exit-animation='slide-right-animation'>
      <neon-animatable key='main'>Foo Page Here</neon-animatable>
      <neon-animatable key='document'>Bar Page Goes Here</neon-animatable>
      <neon-animatable key='baz'>Baz Page, the Best One of the Three</neon-animatable>
    </neon-animated-pages>

    <!-- <routing-element-two route={{tailData}}></routing-element-two> -->
</template>

<script>
    MyLists = Polymer({
      is: 'routing-element-one',

      properties: {

      },
      behaviors: [Polymer.IronResizableBehavior],
      listeners: {
          'iron-resize':'_handleResize',
          'change-content':'_changeContent',
          'update-portlet' : '_updatePortlet'
      },

      observers: [
        '_routeChanged(route.*)',
        '_viewChanged(routeData.view)'
      ],
      _routeChanged:function(e){
          e;
      },
    _viewChanged:function(view) {
          // load data for view
        }
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

This is just my test page to get it working. When I change tab the url updates /polymerui/ + main, document, baz!. Great all good but when I refresh 404.

I just do not see what I have done differently to last time. The obvious thing is that if I search for /polymerui/main for example, that doesn't exist. My point is how the hell did I get it working last time?

p.s. I did not use a hash last time.

Comment: How are you running your polymer app?

Comment: Did you use `.htaccess`. in old project ? Maybe you forgot to copy it?

Comment: @Tanbouz JBoss.